# Issue in Lambda execution time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am working on a project where I have to scrape maximum URLs (placed in an S3 bucket's file) in a limited time and store them in searchable database. Right now I am having an issue while scraping web pages inside aws lambda. I have a function for my task which when runs in a google Collab environment takes only 7-8 seconds to execute and produce the desired results. But the same function when deployed as lambda is taking almost 10X more time to execute. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
import validators
import boto3
from smart_open import open
import nltk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.data.path.append("/tmp")
nltk.download("stopwords", download_dir = "/tmp")


def CrawlingLambda(event, context):
  """
  This lambda crawls a list of webpages, reading URLS from S3 bucket and returns a dictionary
  pairing each URL with its keywords.

    Args:
    http: A pckage inside PoolManager() able to send GET requests
    web_url: url of the website whose availability is required

    Returns:
    bool: Depending upon the response of GET request, this function will return a bool indicating availability of web_url
  
  """
  
  
  results = {}
  
  client = boto3.client('s3')
  
  for line in open('s3://urls-to-monitor/URLs1T.txt', transport_params={'client': client}):
    
    if line[len(line)-1] != '/':
      url = line[:len(line)-2]
    else: url = line
    
    if validation(url) == False:
      continue

    try:
      web_content = scrape_web(url)
      results[url] = web_content
    except: 
      continue
  return results



def validation(url):
  """
  Validates the URL's string. This method use regular expressions for validation at backend.

    Args:
    url: URL to validate

    Returns:
    bool: True if the passes string is a valid URL and False otherwise.
  
  """
  
  return validators.url(url)



def scrape_web(url):
  """
  This function scrapes a given URL's web page for a specific set of keywords.

    Args:
    url: Page's URL to be scraped

    Return:
    filtered_words: A refined list of extracted words from the web page.
  
  """
  
  try:
    res = requests.get(url, timeout=2)
  except:
    raise ValueError

  if res.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError

  
  html_page = res.content

  soup = remove_tags(html_page)

  content = soup.get_text()
  words = re.split(r"\s+|/", content.lower())
  filtered_words = clean_wordlist(words)
  return tuple(filtered_words)



def remove_tags(html):
  """
  Remove the specified tags from HTML response recieved from request.get() method.

    Args:
    html: HTML response of the web page 

    Returns:
    soup: Parsed response of HTML
  
  """
  
  # parse html content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  
  for data in soup(['style', 'script', 'noscript']):
    # Remove tags
    data.decompose()
  
  # return data by retrieving the tag content
  return soup



def clean_wordlist(wordlist):
  """
  This function removes any punctuation marks and stop words from our extracted wordlist.

    Args:
    wordlist: A list of raw words extracted from html response of web page.

    Returns:
    key_words: A filtered list of words containing only key words
    
  """
  
  
  words_without_symbol = []
  
  for word in wordlist:
    #Symbols to ignore
    symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:\"<>?/., "
    
    for i in range(len(symbols)):
      word = word.replace(symbols[i], '')
 
    if len(word) > 0:
      words_without_symbol.append(word)

  #ignoring the stopwords
  key_words = [word for word in words_without_symbol if not word in stopwords.words()]
    
  return key_words
```

Any directions, that why there is much time difference and how can I reduce it.

Comment: Did you tried to rise up the memory available for the lambda execution? by default is 128Mb.

Comment: You might also investigate doing these tasks in parallel using Python multithreading. PS the verb is to *scrape*, not to *scrap* (which means to discard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that you can configure to affect performance is memory allocation. Try increasing the memory allocated for your function, until you have at least the same performance as with Collab.

Billing shouldn't affected much, as it is calculated as the product of memory and execution time.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.